# Recognize the pdf type

Tags: tesseract, apache-tika

Is there any option in Apache Tika to check the pdf type: native pdf (pure) or scanned pdf?

If not maybe I can somehow check it in a tesseract that is used under the hood by Tika

Answer (score 0):

I have not found so far the proper solution to determine is pdf scanned or native but I found a workaround that works for me

I try to extract text without OCR and without internal images

```
pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages(false);
pdfParserConfig.setOcrStrategy(NO_OCR);`
```

It work fast and pretty well for the native pdf. So when the extracted text is non empty I treat a source doc as a native. In other case (the empty response) is a scanned pdf and than I use the OCR strategy to retrieve text